# Closing pyplot figures from previous run

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a python program to do some data analysis, and while developing the code, I have notived that if I do plt.show() at the end of my code, the windows stay on forever unless I manually close each one.

I would like to be able to
1. Either close the old plot when I rerun the program, i.e. at the beginning of each execution, the program should check for any pyplot instances running and close them, or
2. Update the existing figures with the new data, although this would be the less favorable solution, since I am also changing plot types and am unsure how that will affect the replotting.

For the first choice I have tried plt.close('all') at various locations in my code but it either does nothing or immedeately closes the window after it is being shown.

I have also seen people suggesting to just kill the associated process. How would I do that from within the python program?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Figure windows should be closed when the python process finishes. It seems as if you don't end your old python processes correctly. Fresh processes open new windows that are independent of the old process.

Comment: I am using sublime to write and run my code, how would I end the process correctly?